# Android ACRA not reporting crashes

Tags: android, crash, acra

I'm trying to import ACRA to my Android app but it's not reporting force closes. I followed the [guide](http://code.google.com/p/acra/wiki/BasicSetup) but still it doesn't report the crashes. Any suggestion why? xml:

```
 <CheckBoxPreference android:key="acra.enable"
        android:title="@string/pref_disable_acra"
        android:summaryOn="@string/pref_acra_enabled"
        android:summaryOff="@string/pref_acra_disabled"
        android:defaultValue="true"/>
```

Preference class:

```
public class Preferences extends PreferenceActivity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.layout.preferences);

     }
}
```

Here is a picture while enabling/disabling the checkbox:
[image]

Answer (score 4):

Make sure that you have include the ACRA into manisfest too and the allow internet permission .

Try don't use notification crash report, still buggy,  try only use toast show crash method. Also make sure that your apps does not crash before the ACRA loaded.

And at last check your form key and make sure that you have make the form in the Google docs and enable ur ARCA.

Comment: Try look at this sample http://code.google.com/p/acra/source/browse/#svn%2Ftrunk%2Fexamples%2FCrashReport%2Fsrc%2Forg%2Facra%2Fsampleapp

Comment: I put the checkboxPreference, and now when I enable the checkbox, in the LogCat I get "ACRA is disabled" and when I disable the checkbox, I still get the same message!

Comment: Did you check the getpreference is correct/included in your activity ?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the `formKey` parameter is correct, and set the mode to `TOAST` to actually see when a report is being sent. If you are not connected to the Internet, reports will be sent when you connect.

Comment: The formkey is correct. there is internet connection, and I've already set the TOAST message.

Comment: Did you call `ACRA.init()`? Check your form. Make sure the 'acra.enable' preference is set to `true`. That's about it.

Comment: Where should the acra.enabled be set?